# In Celery, only one task runs at the same time?

Tags: python, celery

I have a task, I want it to run once every 10 seconds

at the same time, this task can only run one, can't repeat  run this task

I found two ways：

1).http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/task-cookbook.html#cookbook-task-serial

2).http://engineroom.trackmaven.com/blog/announcing-celery-once/

I don't know this two way is the best, do you have any good idea ?

Comment: I have edited your question to make it look more like what a question is supposed to look like on StackOverflow. Something I cannot do for you, however, is express the constraints that **you** have that would make one method better than the other. Only you can (and need to) do that. Otherwise, you cannot receive a useful answer. If two methods exist, it probably means that each is better than the other in some particular respect.

Comment: You want to run the task every 10 seconds but you also do not want to repeat the task?

Comment: http://loose-bits.com/2010/10/distributed-task-locking-in-celery.html     i ues this